# Make panel appear after time delay?

Tags: javascript

I want to change a panel size to look like an auto collapse at a specific time::

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body   onLoad = "StartClock()"  onunload = "KillClock()">
<script language="JavaScript"> 
 <!--
       var ftext ;
               var clockID = 0;
              var g;
               function UpdateClock() {
                   if (clockID) {
                       clearTimeout(clockID);
                       clockID = 0;
                   }
                   var tDate = new Date();
                   g = ""
                                   + tDate.getHours() + ":"
                                   + tDate.getMinutes() + ":"
                                   + tDate.getSeconds();
                   if (ftext == null) {
                                             ftext = prompt("message time:", "");
                   }
                                   if (g == ftext) {
                                          <%--*here i want the panel to be collapse*--%>
                       g = 0;
                  }

                  if (g == 0)
                  { null }
                  else{
                      clockID = setTimeout("UpdateClock()", 1000);
                  }

               }

               function StartClock() {
                   if (g == 0)
                   { null }
                   else{

                       clockID = setTimeout("UpdateClock()", 500);
                   }
                                  }
               function KillClock() {
                   if (clockID) {
                       clearTimeout(clockID);
                       clockID = 0;
                   }
               }
 //-->
</script>



    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="96px" Width="195px">
    <table style="height: 96px; width: 194px">
    <tr><td></td></tr>

    <tr><td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td></tr>

    </table>
    </asp:Panel>

      </form>
      </body>
</html>
```

I have the clock but I want to collapse the panel where I've marked with `<%-- *here i want the panel to be collapse* --%>`. I want it to be hidden when the page loads then, when the time comes, appear with a collapse, move or fade effect if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript framework is useful for this sort of thing.  It includes loads of [effects](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects) for displaying your panel, like fading, sliding or animating.

Comment: it is not very spacific  answer.but it is realy amazing site ,i'll try to use  the code i hope it work with me, thanks

Comment: $(document.body).click(function () {
      if ($("div:first").is(":hidden")) {
        $("div").show("slow");
      } else {
        $("div").slideUp();
      }
    });
i want to put this effect